# Can't retrieve resources programmatically using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to load a drawable programmatically in my kotlin app via

```
resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.XXX)
```

and all I got was:

```
Method threw 'android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException' exception.
```

whatever the target drawable was.

After trying different things, I finally tried on a newly created Kotlin project, only to find out it didn't work either.
I then created a new Java project, and everything worked flawlessly in this one.

I found nothing about people having the same problem online, I can get the "Resources" object in both project, but it just can't find drawables in the Kotlin one.

Is there anything to do to make it work that I don't know about?

Edit:
I'm getting the resources like this in the newly created project:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    val drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
}
```

This happens whatever the target resource is, drawables, mipmaps, colors...

I'm on Android Studio 3.5.3 with gradle 3.5.3 and Kotlin 1.3.61, API level 26

Project resources are the one added on project creation

Comment: Could you please share your code and resources list in drawable folder?

Comment: Hi, Muro welcome to the SO community. Please show some code of how you are getting the resource so that we can help you.

Comment: I added more informations, but really it happens on any a newly created kotlin project using this single line of code

Comment: I think ic_launcher_foreground has been created in mipmap not in drawable.

Comment: You can give a try for R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground instead of R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground @Muro

Comment: It is actually created in "drawable-24" in my case, but what I forgot to say, is that it applies to ANY resources, even colors and others, whatever the folder is :/

Comment: Could you specify the device API level on which you are getting this exception. According to me your resources are declared in "*-v24" folders and you are getting exception on a device with API level less than 24. Could you please verify the API level?

Comment: I added the information, i'm on API 26, and it happens for any resources, even colors which are not affected by API level

Comment: It's might be because ic_launcher_foreground is not a drawable...

Comment: As I said, this happens with ANY resource really, even colors or anything, so it's not related to drawable, I tested many cases, with mipmap, drawables, etc.. Every case which normally works with Java doesnt work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary fix, and mostly something very interesting.
Taking the example of "ic_launcher_background" as a random drawable, Java gives this result :

[image]

While the exact equivalent code in Kotlin gives us this :
[image]

I don't understand why, but when using a project generated the Kotlin way, the Ids retrievable via **R** just don't match the ones used by the **Resources** class.

So for now I'll use the "getIdentifier()" method to fix my problem, but it really isn"t something you'd want to do naturally.

If someone that has a better understanding of what is going on here could unfold this mystery, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

        val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, null)
}
```

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work because the **R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground** is the problem